# Is there any way to store response entity in redis cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I've tried following code but got error - spring web ResponseEntity can't serialization.

> org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity]

Tried following code:

```java
@Override

@Transactional

@Cacheable(value = "mostFollowedSub", key = "{#root.methodName, #offset, #limit}" )
    public ResponseEntity<Response> mostFollowedSubCategory(int offset, int limit) {
        return subCategoryDao.getMostFollowedSubCategory(offset, limit);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ResponseEntity` is not `Serializable`. Better way is to cache at the service/DAO layer ( in your case `getMostFollowedSubCategory` method of `subCategoryDao`).